# WPF ComboBox - binding to IsEditable in different thread is not consistent

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, converters

I need to set the value of ComboBox.IsEditable according to the existence of items passed in a dictionary as ItemsSource.

The dictionary items are being set in a different thread than the UI thread.

I'm trying to achieve that using the following ComboBox:

```
<local:IsDictionaryNullOrEmptyConverter x:Key="isDictionaryNullOrEmptyConverter" />
...
<ComboBox IsEditable="{Binding MyItemsDictionary, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=isDictionaryNullOrEmptyConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsDictionary}">
<ComboBox>
```

And the following converter :

```
internal class IsDictionaryNullOrEmptyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        IDictionary dic = (IDictionary)value;
        if (dic == null || dic.Count == 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

**The problem** is that the value being received in the converter is sometimes empty dictionary, although it certainly has items (There are items in the ComboBox).

Moreover, there are two ComboBox controls with the same behaviour. The two of them receives different dictionaries as ItemsSource in the same thread, one of them gets an empty value into the converter and the other gets a full one.

Comment: Do you update the `MyItemsDictionary` property with a completely new dictionary every time the number of items in the dictionary changes? If not, then the UI will not be notified when that happens. In that case, you better bind to `MyItemsDictionary.Count` with a suitable converter and make sure your dictionary implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: I Did used MyItemsDictionary.Add, I switched it to update the property and it works great !

Comment: You don't really have control over the order is processes binding.  It  could evaluate the IsEditable before there are values and then not hit is again.  I know not an answer and that is why this is a comment.  I would have a bool property IsEditable that you call INPC.

Comment: Blam, I want this ability to be generic for every bind of dictionary with any combobox. So boolean for every combobox is not a good solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample solution and it works as expected. The `IsEditable` Property is always updated when the `ItemsSource`property is updated.

My View

```
<Window x:Class="MultipleDataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceOne, Mode=OneWay}" IsEditable="{Binding SourceOne, Converter={StaticResource Converter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceTwo, Mode=OneWay}" IsEditable="{Binding SourceOne, Converter={StaticResource Converter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

CodeBehind

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MultipleDataGrid
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MultipleDataGrid
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private static readonly object _lockOne = new object();
        private static readonly object _lockTwo = new object();

        private Dictionary<string, string> _sourceOne;

        public Dictionary<string, string> SourceOne
        {
            get { return _sourceOne; }
        }

        private Dictionary<string, string> _sourceTwo;

        public Dictionary<string, string> SourceTwo
        {
            get { return _sourceTwo; }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            _sourceOne = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            _sourceTwo = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_sourceOne, _lockOne); //Thread safety
            BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_sourceTwo, _lockTwo); //Thread safety

            //To delay the addition of the items to the dictionary and then raise a property changed at last after the task is executed
            Task.Run(async () => await LoadDictionary()).ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Task Ran");
                    if (t.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        RaisePropertyChanged("SourceOne");
                        RaisePropertyChanged("SourceTwo");
                    }
                });
        }

        private async Task LoadDictionary()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _sourceOne.Add("KeyOneOne", "ValueOne");
                _sourceOne.Add("KeyOneTwo", "ValueTwo");
                _sourceOne.Add("KeyOneThree", "ValueThree");
                _sourceOne.Add("KeyOneFour", "ValueFour");
                _sourceOne.Add("KeyOneFive", "ValueFive");
            });

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _sourceTwo.Add("KeyTwoOne", "ValueOne");
                _sourceTwo.Add("KeyTwoTwo", "ValueTwo");
                _sourceTwo.Add("KeyTwoThree", "ValueThree");
                _sourceTwo.Add("KeyTwoFour", "ValueFour");
                _sourceTwo.Add("KeyTwoFive", "ValueFive");
            });


        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            var pc = PropertyChanged;
            if (pc != null)
                pc(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }

    }
}
```

I used the converter used by you as it is. I moved the resource definition to the `App.xaml`

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:IsDictionaryNullOrEmptyConverter x:Key="Converter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```